# Django - Edit templates from django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Can I save templates in my db and edit them from django-admin?
My idea is to create a model for templates:

```
class DbTemplate(models.Model):
    css_class = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Database Template"
        verbose_name_plural = "Database Templates"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and register it in django-admin:

```
from .models import DbTemplate

admin.site.register(DbTemplate)
```

in my urls.py set a default view for r"^page/" that load the correct template, is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) templates manually in your views and return the resulting [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse). Here is a rough example (which you should modify according to your use case):

```
from django.template import Context, Template
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    ...
    context = {'value': something, 'another_var': something_else}
    # Here, instead of returning `render`, render the template using the context manually
    template_content = DbTemplate.objects.get(name='my_template').content
    template = Template(template_content)
    return HttpResponse(template.render(Context(context)))
```